# Нужно ли для адаптивной верстки использовать dpi в медиа запросе?

Tags: css

Нужно ли для адаптивной верстки проверять dpi в медиа запросе?
Или хватит проверки в px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы делаете адаптивный дизайн вебсайта, т.е. только для отображения на экране - то резолюцию проверять не надо. Пикселей достаточно.
Скажем так, для 98% случаев - достаточно.

Однако, если Вы настраиваете что-то под конкретное устройство (например, малоформатный принтер), тогда это может иметь смысл. Но опять же, это при условии, что у Вас будет распечатываться что-то специфическое.